# How to tighten this kitchen sink faucet?

Tags: plumbing, kitchens

I have an unknown model of kitchen faucet, with two problems.

1. The handle  is loose, i.e. it has a lot of play before it starts
   adjusting the flow.
2. The pull-out sprayer hose doesn't seat properly when retracted, so it wiggles.

Both problems are quickly illustrated in this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GRVtZPf-4zw

EDIT: I got the handle off, and found the below mechanism inside.  The left piece screws on top of the right piece, creating a groove where the white piece is shorter, and there's a metal piece that slides back and forth in that groove.  This plastic is clearly worn, so I guess I just need a new one.
[image]
About the sprayer problem, here is a photo showing it a little better.
[image]

Comment: First, great idea for showing exactly what the problem is. Regarding the loose handle, have you tried putting a mirror behind it to look for a screw? As for the loose spout, does the faucet have a pull out hose attached to the spout?

Comment: I don't see a set screw back there. Unless it's hidden under the red/blue dot on the front of the handle. Yes, there is a hose. Edited.

Comment: The red/blue dot or a name tag are common locations for covering screws.

Answer (score 2):

I can help you with number one, number two I'd have to see more angles and photos of both sides of the mating connector. (EDIT: There's magnets and a weight that makes those things retract.. is the weight caught up on something under the sink?)

I had a handle that did this too. This is caused by one or many occasions when excessive force is applied to the handle, breaking or bending the metal inside.

There's an set screw hidden right below the red/blue dot, use a razor to catch the edge of it and pop it off. Watch your sink drains, they're like magnets for that darn dot. Once you back out the set screw about 3/4ths of the way, the handle will come right off the top.

You'll find the inside of the handle has a hollow rectangle that slides over a solid metal rectangle on the valve. You'll likely find that the metal of the hollow rectangle has been bent.

I fixed mine by using a vice grip to squeeze in and tighten the sides of the female side of the rectangle back up. Test it for fit, make sure it's good, then take it back off and wrap it with steel wire and epoxy. I must have layered mine in about a quarter inch thick. Make sure to leave clearance for the set screw, and definitely leave the screw in place to protect the threads from the epoxy in case it drips.

The idea is to reset and strengthen the metal in place. Wire alone won't do the trick, since it'll round right out too, the epoxy gives it the strength. You might even be able to use stranded copper wire and solder to replace the epoxy. There's more than one way to skin a <s>cat</s> faucet.

Alternatively, a lot of faucets have lifetime warranties that they hope you don't remember about. I once called up the manufacturer and got a brand new handle shipped out.

Comment: Cover the drain with something (bowl, rag, plate). *Watching* the drain doesn't stop it from being a magnet for small parts.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. My faucet isn't quite the same as yours. You're right about the set screw. But beneath that is a different mechanism.  There's a metal piece that moves in a plastic groove.  It pushes the plastic part vertically to adjust the flow, and the  ends of the groove limit the horizontal handle movement. The plastic piece has been worn out, I can see where it's thinner than it should be. So I guess I need to replace it. Any idea what brand this is?